# how to import a full page into a different website when importe page has google maps v2?

Tags: google-maps

I am tring to import a client's page (the whole page) into mine yet, even though we both granted access to each other's domains, I still get this error message: This web site needs a different Google Maps API key. A new key can be generated at http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/introduction.html#Obtaining_Key.

This is a page you can visit to see a live example: http://web-success-marketing.com/beton-region/beton.php

This is the actual page getting imported: www.acces411.ca/listing/results.php?keyword=béton&where=Mont+Saint+Hilaire

and this is a more detailed rendition of the situation: groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/google-maps-api/G0SJ1Wud4nc

Do you think you help solve this issue?

Seb.

Answer (score 0):

Seb,
    your question is a little unclear, do you want to continue using the Version 2 key?

If so you need to find out the google account of the user who created the **original key** in the www.acces411.ca and then add your domain to  the **Referers** list.

If you are unable to do this not you will have to migrate to version 3 and use a google account to create a new key.
Regards,

Lea.